# communication with underground mines?

Tags: frequency

I have a meter that will analyze limited RF spectrum in my area. One frequency that keeps coming up is **2.498 kHz**. An FCC site listed that as the frequency used to communicate with underground mines. Is that correct, and if so, why would it be in my neighborhood?

There were a series of repeating frequencies, I'll list the most prominent, and hopefully you can tell me what most likely are producing them:

> - 2.502 GHz,
> - 672 MHz,
> - 640 and 624 MHz,
> - 72 MHz,
> - 2.623 MHz is a constant,
> - 550 kHz is a constant at -30 dbm,

then

> - 159,
> - 168,
> - 172,
> - 219,
> - 378, and
> - 471 kHz, all averaging -40 dBm.

That's a limited piece of data, but even that seems like alot. What
     are these coming from, and especially, is that 2.498 kHz really for
     communicating with mines? Thanks for your help.

Comment: What sort of antenna is it connected to?  2.4 kHz will not be easily detected by a small antenna.  And if it's not detecting cellular phones at ~900 and ~1800 MHz, it's not working.

Comment: Isn't 2.5 GHz area where microwave ovens work?

Comment: Where is your "neighborhood?" There might be mines for coal, salt, minerals, etc.

Comment: Frequencies in the 3kHz range have been used to [communicate with submarines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communication_with_submarines).

Comment: 550 kHz is in the AM broadcast band.  Around here, 72MHz is used by a company (can't remember their name) that makes synchronized clocks.  The ones in the ~100kHz could well be aircraft navigation beacons.  If memory serves, 600MHz is in the TV broadcast band.  There is a WWV signal on 2.5MHz, but that's probably not what you're seeing.

Comment: Have you considered harmonics? You likely need to use a good bandpass, and know your rf spectrum analyzer well.

Comment: 2.5GHz is most likely WiFi/Bluetooth

Comment: Microwave ovens are 2.450GHz from memory

Comment: We can't answer your question without more information about your setup.  What are you using for an antenna?  What kind of "meter" are you using?  What kind of transmission line is there between the antenna and the "meter", and how long is it?